# How to move a tab to the bottom of the sidebar in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard, sidebar

I have a shiny dashboard built with `shinyDashboardPlus`. I have a sidebar with several tabs - as usual, they are aligned in the top left corner.

My sidebar scrolling is fixed with `style = "position: fixed;"`.

I want to add a Help / Contact tab, but I want it to sit in the bottom left corner of the sidebar. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to style the according li-tag via css.

Please check the follwing:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets",
               badgeLabel = "new", badgeColor = "green")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
      #sidebarItemExpanded > ul > :last-child {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;
      }

    "))),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              h2("Dashboard tab content")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets", id = "widgetstabid",
              h2("Widgets tab content")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar with CSS, but I tried this and discovered two issues: (1) this doesn't work when the sidebar position is fixed (no scrolling), as a result the last tab title gets overlaid on the second-to-last tab title; (2) if the length of the dashboard's body content is longer than one screen, the tab title positioned in the bottom left of the sidebar disappears from the first screen and goes all the way down -- becoming visible only after scrolling down. Also, how do you go about positioning more than 1 tab title in the bottom?

Comment: Instead of adding several new requirements to an existing question you should post a follow-up question.  I can't guess what you want unless you write it down here. Furthermore, please provide example code showing the issues.